# set position X/Y of a view before API 11 (Android)

Tags: android, view

i would like to set position of my view.
There are the methods setX/setY or setLeft/setTop but these methods are available since API 11.
What is the solution in order to have this fonctionnality in other API.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which layout you're using. With `RelativeLayout` you can do the following:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)child.getLayoutParams();

layoutParams.leftMargin = x;
layoutParams.topMargin = y;

child.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195768/android-use-of-view-setx-and-sety-in-api-8/28151869#28151869

Answer (score 0):

try to override onDraw method and set translation x/y your canvas ?

```
@Override
protected function onDraw(Canvas c){
    c.save();
    c.translate(x,y);
    c.restore();
}
```

I think it's not a good solution but it the only idea i had.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I could get to work 'out-of-the-box' was setting the views padding.

```
View.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
```

It isn't the best solution but it will work on API's older than 11 and will simulate moving the view in a X, Y fashion.

Hope that helps!