# How to dynamically create a large number of imageView in Android

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

Hello I am making a jigsaw puzzle application and for that i have 16 made smaller bitmaps out of a large scaled bitmap with height = width = 240. Now I have to dynamically display these bitmaps in a single activity at one time. The code I tried is not working properly as it is displaying all images in a single row and size of image is too small. Here is the code:

```
public void display()
    {
        float x =0;
        float y = 0;
        LinearLayout llMain = new LinearLayout(this);
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            LinearLayout llRow = new LinearLayout(this);
            for(int j=0;j<tiles.length/4;j++)
            {
                ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
                iv.setImageBitmap(tiles[j]);// get bitmap from image path
                iv.setX(x);
                iv.setY(y);
                x = y = x + 60;
                llRow.addView(iv);
            }
            llMain.addView(llRow);
        }
        setContentView(llMain);
       }
}
```

Here is the LogCat:

```
01-05 00:32:35.820: D/dalvikvm(11346): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 47K, 52% free 2599K/5379K, external 1990K/2108K, paused 135ms
01-05 00:32:44.183: D/dalvikvm(11346): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 43K, 50% free 2739K/5379K, external 2477K/2527K, paused 18ms
01-05 00:32:45.156: I/dalvikvm(11346): Could not find method android.widget.ImageView.setX, referenced from method com.maju.jigsawpuzzle.PlayBoard.display
01-05 00:32:45.156: W/dalvikvm(11346): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3236: Landroid/widget/ImageView;.setX (F)V
01-05 00:32:45.156: D/dalvikvm(11346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x002e
01-05 00:32:45.156: D/dalvikvm(11346): VFY: dead code 0x0031-003e in Lcom/maju/jigsawpuzzle/PlayBoard;.display ()V
01-05 00:32:45.179: D/AndroidRuntime(11346): Shutting down VM
01-05 00:32:45.179: W/dalvikvm(11346): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
01-05 00:32:45.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11346): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-05 00:32:45.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11346): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.ImageView.setX
01-05 00:32:45.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11346):    at com.maju.jigsawpuzzle.PlayBoard.display(PlayBoard.java:164)
01-05 00:32:45.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11346):    at com.maju.jigsawpuzzle.PlayBoard.shuffleArray(PlayBoard.java:143)
01-05 00:32:45.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11346):    at com.maju.jigsawpuzzle.PlayBoard.breakImage(PlayBoard.java:123)
01-05 00:32:45.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11346):    at com.maju.jigsawpuzzle.PlayBoard.onCreate(PlayBoard.java:40)
01-05 00:32:45.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11346):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-05 00:32:45.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
01-05 00:32:45.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
01-05 00:32:45.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-05 00:32:45.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11346):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
01-05 00:32:45.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11346):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-05 00:32:45.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11346):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-05 00:32:45.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
01-05 00:32:45.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11346):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-05 00:32:45.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11346):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-05 00:32:45.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11346):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
01-05 00:32:45.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11346):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
01-05 00:32:45.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11346):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Line 164 is the line:

iv.setX(x);

Does anybody know the solution? Moreover I have to register onClick with them...

Thanks in advancce

Comment: What API level are you running this on? setX() was only added in API level 11.

Comment: With 8 But I did mentioned @TargetApi(11) as the compiler asked me to do so

Comment: Just because you're targeting a higher API doesn't mean it can run on lower devices. If you're running this on a device below 11 you'll see exactly this runtime error.

Comment: so is there an alternate way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use setX/setY if you want to support old android versions.
Instead set LayoutParams (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) to specify ImageView's x/y params. Read this post: [Android - Use of view.setX() and setY in api 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195768/android-use-of-view-setx-and-sety-in-api-8)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTranslationX%28float%29)

> the setX method is only available in API level 11.

That means that your app will crash if you are on Android 2.x.

I guess that you are getting some Lint warning in your code, isn't it?

I have never used the setX method and cannot help, but I hope you can find some alternatives on pre-Honeycomb devices.

When you will have find it you can use

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){}
```