# Placing coordinates button android in 2.3.3

Tags: android, button, imageview, set

I created an app that should put a few buttons ( or imageview) at random, I pass the maximum and minimum values ​​and from there take the coordinates.

The problem is that in 4.2.2 compilation is perfect, but I seek to work for 2.3.3 because I want to share my application in google play.

i use android 4.2.2. to do the app.

button.setX() and button.setY()

but in android 2.3.3 ( API level 10 ) can use the methods

Do you know how could I in API level 10?

Thank you very much!

Comment: if you are getting any bug, just paste the logcat here in ur question

Comment: i no have bugs or something, only when i change to 2.3.3 from 4.2.2 eclipse sais cant use the "button.setX" or "button.SetY()"

Comment: it means these methods are not available with api level-10, means for android 2.3.3

Comment: thx sherlock, i know, but u know how i can do it with other methods

Comment: You should look at this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/12195999/2140191

Comment: I made an answer, could you accept @CristianCV? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12195999/2140191

```
//The WRAP_CONTENT parameters can be replaced by an absolute width and height or the FILL_PARENT option)
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
params.leftMargin = 50; //Your X coordinate
params.topMargin = 60; //Your Y coordinate
```

After that add the LayoutParams to the button with:

```
button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
setTranslationX(float xVal)
```

public float getX ()

Added in API level 11
The visual x position of this view, in pixels. This is equivalent to the translationX property plus the current left property.

Returns
The visual x position of this view, in pixels.

Comment: i want do it in API level 10, api level 11 is for android 3.0 and the most android devices have a smaller version of the three