# Android: Replace setX() for lower API's

Tags: android, android-layout

I am writing a method that draws a layout ontop of buttons. My problem is with the position of the layout that I am creating on lower API's. On newer I am using the `setX()` and `setY()` methods but since that is not working on lower I tried with setting the layout params as described here [Android - Use of view.setX() and setY in api 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195768/android-use-of-view-setx-and-sety-in-api-8/12195999#12195999) but I am not getting the results I want. With this

```
int[] location = new int[2];
button.getLocationOnScreen(location);
int x = location[0];
int y = location[1];
borderRelativeLayout.setX(x);
borderRelativeLayout.setY(y);
viewGroup.addView(borderRelativeLayout)
```

I am achieving this:
[correct position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGe4O.png)

but if I use this code to support lower API's

```
relativeLayoutparams.leftMargin = x;
relativeLayoutparams.topMargin = y;
viewGroup.addView(borderRelativeLayout, relativeLayoutparams);
```

I am getting this as a result: [incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BxZm.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For API 1:

```
int[] location = new int[2];
button.getLocationOnScreen(location);
int x = location[0];
int y = location[1];
borderRelativeLayout.offsetLeftAndRight(x - borderRelativeLayout.getLeft());
borderRelativeLayout.offsetTopAndBottom(y - borderRelativeLayout.getTop());
```

EDIT:
Did you consider a background drawable for desired effect?

Comment: Thanks, but `setLeft` and `setTop` for relative layout also requires api 11. 
What do you mean by using background drawable? Can you be more spesific?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realized that. You can use offsetLeftAndRight and offsetTopAndBottom. Anyway, what about the drawables? You can set the border using drawable.

Comment: I am using drawable to create the border on the layout. And I am using a layout to do this and not directly to the button, cause I don't want to change the style of a button if it's a custom one. I will try your method with offset now.
Update: same results.

Comment: Why are you positioning the layout manually? Do you have one RelativeLayout with the border drawable for every button?

Comment: Yes. I am creating them dynamically. Whenever I detect a button in a view, I place a border around it.

Comment: If you have to do it this way, you can create FrameLayout with the border, get layoutParams from the Button, remove the Button from the layout and add it to new FrameLayout (setPadding so you will see the border), then add the FrameLayout to original layout with original Button's layoutParams. Better will be to use custom ViewGroup for the buttons and override the addView method, where you can set the border.

Comment: Positioning views manually doesn't look like a good idea (when not using custom ViewGroup). Also having so many layouts could cause performance issues.

Comment: Maybe better way will be to override onDraw method of your layout holding all buttons. Than, after every button is drawn, you can iterate through all buttons and draw border around them.

Comment: Well I can't override onDraw cause I don't know the layout cause I am writing this method for a library. But thanks for all the suggestions.